# AirPods Max connected but no longer working reliably

Tags: airpods

Since the firmware 5B59, I have to hard-reset my AirPods Max every day.

They are connected via Bluetooth. But I cannot change the Noise Control settings in the Settings app on iPad. There is no sound and the active noise cancellation that I experience usually when I put my AirPods on is not switched on. I don‘t even hear the „dong“ sound when I put them on when this problem occurs.

I can solve this problem by pressing the two buttons on my AirPods Pro for about 10 seconds. Then I can re-connect and everything works for about a day, even when I use them for hours. The next day, or earlier, however, I have the same problem.

This basically rules out a hardware problem. I chatted with Apple Support and the person finally agreed that it is likely a firmware problem.

Unfortunately, my coverage expired a few days ago and therefore Apple  cannot do anything unless I pay for the repair. Given that these are quite expensive headphones, I expect them to work way longer than two years.

Does anyone have similar problems? What can I do?

Update 2023-03-06: Other users describe similar problems on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Airpodsmax/comments/11djcdr/connection_problems/).

Update 2023-03-12: I contacted Apple support and spoke with various agents for a long time. They finally told me that it is a hardware defect and that my only option is an exchange (no repair possible). Since AppleCare+ has just expired, such an exchange would cost 520 €, i.e., more than what I had to pay for a new device. This experience reminded me how much I liked my Bose QC…

Comment: If it exhibits a problem directly after a firmware update, then it stands to reason that a firmware upgrade or downgrade will fix it.  The best course of action now is to notify Apple:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/airpods/